# Coq - Proving strict inequality involving bigops in Ssreflect

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

I am trying to prove the following using the Mathematical Components library:

```
Lemma bigsum_aux (i: 'I_q) (j: 'I_q) (F G : 'I_q -> R):
  (forall i0, F i0 <= G i0) /\ (exists j0, F j0 < G j0) ->
  \sum_(i < q) F i < \sum_(i < q) G i.
```

Initially, I was trying to find some Lemma equivalent to `bigsum_aux` in the documentation of `ssralg` or `bigop`, but I couldn't find any; so this is what I have been able to do so far:

```
Proof.
 move => [Hall Hex]. rewrite ltr_neqAle ler_sum; last first.
 - move => ? _. exact: Hall.
 - rewrite andbT. (* A: What now? *)
```

Any help or pointers towards relevant lemmas would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split the sum in the "bad" (<) part, then the rest is trivial:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Open Scope ring_scope.
Import Num.Theory.

Lemma bigsum_aux (R : numDomainType) q (i: 'I_q) (j: 'I_q) (F G : 'I_q -> R)
      (hle : forall i0, F i0 <= G i0) z (hlt : F z < G z) :
  \sum_(i < q) F i < \sum_(i < q) G i.
Proof.
by rewrite [\sum__ F _](bigD1 z) ?[\sum__ G _](bigD1 z) ?ltr_le_add ?ler_sum.
Qed.
```

Comment: This is pretty nifty use of rewrite! Thanks :)